# Architecture of folders with require/include

Tags: php, class, methods, mysqli, require

i have problem, i building my own CMS, where i using directories

Main directory
 - index.php
 - /moduls
 - /functions

/functions

- db-class.php

/moduls/galerie

- /functions/galerie-class.php

when i accesing out of folder galerie, it's showing me `Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on null in D:\xampp\htdocs\imcm\admin\moduls\galerie\functions\galerie-class.php on line 98`

db-class.php looks like

```
    <?php
if(!class_exists("DB")){
    class DB{
        public function __construct(){
            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "imcm");

            if($mysqli->connect_errno)
            {
                printf("Připojení selhalo %s\n",$mysqli->connect_error());
                exit();

            }

            $this->connection = $mysqli;
        }


        public function insert($query){
            $result = $this->connection->query($query);

            return $this->connection->insert_id;
        }

        public function update($query)
        {
            $result = $this->connection->query($query);
        }

        public function select($query){
            $result = $this->connection->query($query);

            while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){
                    $results[] = $obj;
            }
            return $results;

        }

        public function delete($query){
            $result = $this->connection->query($query);
        }
    }
}


$db = new DB;



?>
```

and galerie-class.php

```
   <?php
if(!file_exists("../../functions/db-class.php"))
{
    require_once("functions/db-class.php"); 

}
else
{
    require_once("../../functions/db-class.php");
}


if(!class_exists("GALERIE"))
{
    class GALERIE{
        function newGallery($galerie, $popis){
            global $db;
            if($galerie == ""){
                return "Pole nemůže být prázdné.";
            }
            else{
                $query = "INSERT into galerie values(null,'".$galerie."','".$popis."', '".Time()."')";

                return $db->insert($query);

            }
        }


        function updateTitle($id, $title){
            global $db;

            $query = "UPDATE fotky set title='".$title."' where id='".$id."'";
            return $db->update($query);
        }

        function deleteImage($id)
        {
            global $db;

            $query = "DELETE from fotky where id='".$id."'";
            return $db->delete($query);

        }

        function uploadImage($soubor, $id, $maxWidth, $maxHeight){
            global $db;
            $imagesize = getimagesize($soubor);

            switch($imagesize[2]){
                case 1 : $img = imagecreatefromgif($soubor); break;
                case 2 : $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($soubor); break;
                case 3 : $img = imagecreatefrompng($soubor); break;
                default : $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($soubor); break;
            }



            $height = $maxHeight;
            $width = $maxWidth;
            $width = round($imagesize[0] * $width / $imagesize[0]);

            $height = round($imagesize[1] * $height / $imagesize[1]);

            $img2 = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

            imagecopyresampled($img2, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $imagesize[0], $imagesize[1]);

            $query = "INSERT into fotky values(null, '".$id."', '', '', '".Time()."')";
            $imageId = $db->insert($query);

            $query = "UPDATE fotky set name='".$id."_".$imageId.".jpg' where id='".$imageId."'";
            $db->update($query);

            imagejpeg($img2, "miniatury/".$id."_".$imageId.".jpg", 100);


            move_uploaded_file($soubor, "original/".$id."_".$imageId.".jpg");

        }



        function showFotky($idGalerie){
            global $db;

            $query = "SELECT * from fotky where gal_id='$idGalerie' order by id DESC";

            return $db->select($query);

        }

    function showGalleries(){
            global $db;


            $query = "SELECT * from galerie order by id DESC";
            return $db->select($query); //line 98
        }




    }
}






?>
```

thanks for any response!

Comment: And which line is line 98?

Comment: Just consider using an autoloader instead of all those manual includes, it makes life so much easier

Comment: I added comment to line 98, it is on the end of galerie-class.php

Comment: OK i have it! only define global $db in db-class.php, thank you anyway

Comment: @koca79331 BTW: you can write your own answer if you figured it out! And you can accept your own answer too!

Answer (score 0):

Only define global $db in db-class.php